# Configure external auth server as OpenID Connect identity provider in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I want to configure a Spring Boot service as OpenID Connect identity provider in AWS Cognito for authentication and authorization.
[image]
Previously, on my local system I was using keycloak instead of AWS Cognito. In order to run my service on https protocol, I created a self-signed certificate on my local system. Also in order to configure this service  as OpenID Connect identity provider in AWS Cognito, it is also necessary to run this service on https protocol. When i was running the auth service locally on my system with keycloak, I also had to add this certificate in the keycloak truststore. My code can be seen below that I have written in order to deploy keycloak on the docker.

```
  keycloak:
    container_name: "key-server"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: "admin"
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "pondelok"
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
    image: "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.1"
    ports:
      - "9380:9380"
    extra_hosts:
      - "auth-server:host-gateway"
    restart: unless-stopped

    volumes:
      - "../keycloak/providers:/opt/keycloak/providers"
      - "../keycloak/realms_local:/tmp/import"
      - "../keycloak/keystore:/home"

    command:
      [
          'start-dev --auto-build',
          '--http-enabled=true',
          '--http-port=9380',
          '--spi-truststore-file-file=/home/oceankeystore.jks',
          '--spi-truststore-file-password=password',
          '--spi-truststore-file-hostname-verification-policy=ANY',
          '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
          '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
          '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/tmp/import',
          '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING',
          '-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled',
          '--log-level=DEBUG,io.quarkus:INFO,liquibase:INFO,org.hibernate:INFO,org.infinispan:INFO,org.keycloak.services.scheduled:INFO,org.keycloak.transaction:INFO,io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache:INFO,org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan:INFO'
      ]
```

Now I want to deploy my application on AWS. I am replacing keycloak with AWS Cognito. Now my question is that how I can add the self-signed certificate that I created on my local system in AWS Cognito so that successful connection can be established between AWS Cognito and my auth service which is acting as OpenID Connect identity provider. I am unable to figure this out. I am unable to find out where in AWS Cognito, I can add my self-signed certificate. Can anyone guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Your "auth service" deployed on AWS should use a certificate with trusted authority (not a self-signed one). Have a look at solutions like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) or AWS Certificate Manager.

Comment: I have searched about AWS Certificate Manager, but I discovered that  if I create certificates in AWS Certificate Manager they can not be downloaded. Also such certificates can only be used with AWS resources but in my case we have an external Spring boot service that we want to use as auth server and we want to configure it as OpenID Connect identity provider as I have mentioned above. Also I will have to include that certificate in my spring boot auth service that is not possible because certificate created in AWS certificate manager can not be downloaded.

Comment: then you have the let's encrypt sollution I mentioned